# How does git identify the correct path to push to when SSH URL path changes during renaming of the remote repo?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I created a repo on Github and cloned it on my local PC using the SSH path which was like:-

> git@github.com:user-name/orig_repo.git

That is exactly the URL path that can be seen in the config file of the .git folder in my cloned directory. Then I renamed the Remote Repo, which changed the SSH URL based on the new name:-

> git@github.com:user-name/new_repo.git

Since git doesn't care about the name of the local directory as long as the path to which you push is defined properly, I renamed my local directory to the same name of the new repo as *new_repo*, which is just for sake of my convenience and not a necessity.

What is of more importance is that the path to which it should push has changed ideally, but I still see the original SSH path in my config file, which is:-

> git@github.com:user-name/orig_repo.git

But despite the older path, I can push all changes and it reflects in the remote repo properly. I am not sure how this mismatch between the SSH paths is handled. Does git redirect the changes automatically to the new path?

I am using VS Code for running the Git commands, in case it has any effect.

Comment: This is functionality implemented by GitHub as a convenience - other git hosting services also do the same, it is not a feature of git itself.

Comment: When I push to a renamed repo with the CLI, I usually get a message saying it's pushing to the renamed repo. The VSCode Git plugin might hide it, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to GitHub's documentation on [renaming repos](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/renaming-a-repository), when you rename a repo, the old name will redirect everything to the new name, so that any old sandboxes (like yours) and other stuff will keep working.

If you think about it, it's a rather essential feature for GitHub and other hosting services: otherwise, renaming a repo would break a lot of things!

It is recommended that you update your remote, but it's not required, and you can take the time you need to update all the references you might have to it.

The old names will work forever, as long as you don't create a new repo under that old name.

Comment: +1. There’s more to it on GitHub I’m sure, but it can be considered analogous to creating a symlink from old to new locations - which is one way to achieve the same result on your own git server.

Comment: I did have a feeling that this might be the case but wasn't sure if Github is fixing it or VS Code. The documentation clarifies it.